# Connecting to a MSSQL database with PHP Connection Login failed for user

Tags: php, sql-server

I am at the start of developing a simple script that will log into a MSSQL database with a PHP script. I have got a connection between both servers but keep getting this error:

Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: message: Login failed for user '$username'. (severity 14) in /directory/ on line no

the code I am using to connect is simply :

$var = mssql_connect('ip:port','$username','$password');

Any help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes from your variables:

```
 $var = mssql_connect('ip:port',$username,$password);
```

Comment: Apologies in the script they are strings not variables, i only used these to not put the password etc on the site

Comment: are you sure? because the error message says "login failed for user $username" - which means the variable is being passed as a string

Comment: I replaced that aswell because i didnt want to give the username away aswell apologies